# Can we add parameter in datatable.select in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I like to know is it possible to add parameter in datatable.select(expression).For example

```
string query="Name=@Name";          
//dt is comming from database.
dt.Select(query);
```

How to add this parameter `@Name`. I need to compare a value which contains single quote and it gets failed in the above case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `String.Format`, you need to escape single quotes with two:

```
string query = string.Format("Name='{0}'", name.Replace(@"'", "''"));
var rows = dt.Select(query);
```

or, if you want to use `Like`:

```
string query = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", name.Replace(@"'", "''"));
```

(note that a `DataTable` is not vulnerable to sql-injection since it's an in-memory object)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not concerned about sql injection. I need to compare a value which contains single quote and it gets failed in the above case.

Comment: @user1685652: Since i normally use LINQ meanwhile i have forgotten that you need to escape the single quotes. You just have to double them, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass only expression to Select method.

In case if you need to pass the parameter dynamically then you can try this.

`string Exp = "Name ='" +  variable + "'";`

```
dt.select(Exp);
```

Comment: -1, no discussion on how to escape `variable` (which is kind of the whole point of using parameters).