# How to datatable.Select() filter numeric

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I want to filter my datatable. I use `datatable.Select()` to filter but one of the condition `UnitPrice` always not match the data. This column `UnitPrice` is *numeric* and has a decimal point, like 0.1750.

How to modify my code? thanks.

I try:

```
var result = 
 dt_Excel.Select(@" ID = '" + detailrow["Details_MasterID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And PatternCode = '" + detailrow["PatternCode"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And StyleID  = '" + detailrow["StyleID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And BrandID  = '" + detailrow["BrandID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And SeasonID  = '" + detailrow["SeasonID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And UnitPrice  = '" +detailrow["UnitPrice"].ToString() + "'"
```

try again:

```
var result = 
 dt_Excel.Select(@" ID = '" + detailrow["Details_MasterID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And PatternCode = '" + detailrow["PatternCode"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And StyleID  = '" + detailrow["StyleID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And BrandID  = '" + detailrow["BrandID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And SeasonID  = '" + detailrow["SeasonID"].ToString() + "'"
  + " And UnitPrice  = '" +Convert.ToDecimal( detailrow["UnitPrice"]) +"'"
```

Comment: @mjwills: that is not sql but a way to query the in-memory collection `DataTable`. No injection possible ;-)

Comment: You should use `Linq-To-DataTable` and cast the columns to the correct type, f.e. with `DataRowExtension.Field`.

Comment: What would happen if `detailrow["PatternCode"].ToString()` had a single quote in it @TimSchmelter ? Would that work? If not, what could be done to fix it (possibly https://stackoverflow.com/a/18535163/34092)? _Apologies if that is a dumb question._

Comment: @mjwills: i havent said that it works, i just have said that it's not vulnerable to sql injection because no database is involved. I prefer LInq-To-DataTable anyway where you have compile time safety, the full .NET framework support and no odd pseudo-sql syntax to remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `'` for numerics.

Try changing:

```
And UnitPrice  = '" +detailrow["UnitPrice"].ToString() +"'"
```

to:

```
And UnitPrice  = " +detailrow["UnitPrice"].ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

You were suppose to pass the `UnitPrice` as `String` in DataTable Select using `' (single quotes)`.

I believe that except `PatternCode` all other doesn't require single quotes to filter a record if `PatternCode` has string literals.

Try the below code snippet:

```
var result = dt_Excel.Select(@" ID = " + detailrow["Details_MasterID"] + "'"
                                         + " And PatternCode = '" + detailrow["PatternCode"] + "'"
                                         + " And StyleID  = " + detailrow["StyleID"]
                                         + " And BrandID  = " + detailrow["BrandID"]
                                         + " And SeasonID  = " + detailrow["SeasonID"]
                                         + " And UnitPrice  = " + detailrow["UnitPrice"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: @VictorLin Glad it helped. :)